# Send message to specific user from android device to other device

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm implementing simple chat server that work fine in kind of browsers, but couldn't send message to specific user from android to other android device or android device to users which connected from browser, server said me user isn't connected, but in browser can detected correctly and sending message,i don't know whats problem, i'm using [nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat) library on android and all of other feature work fine

## Html for test and sending message to specific user:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Document
    </title>
    </meta>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#login').click(function () {
                socket.emit('login', {username: 'a', password: 'a'});
            });

            $('#mesage').click(function () {
                socket.emit('requestMoney', 'mahdi');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        var socket = new io.connect('http://192.168.1.35:3000', {
            port      : 3000,
            transports: ['websocket']
        });
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log('connected!');
        });
        socket.on('message', function (message) {
            console.log("hello ::::::::" + message);
        });
        socket.on('success', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h3 id="login">login</h3>

<h3 id="mesage">mesage</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

## My simplified nodejs server:

```
var socket      = require('socket.io'),
    express     = require('express'),
    app         = express(),
    server      = require('http').createServer(app),
    io          = socket.listen(server),
    port        = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    mysql       = require('mysql'),
    multer      = require('multer'),
    uuid        = require('node-uuid'),
    datetime    = require('node-datetime'),
    moment      = require('moment'),
    bcrypt      = require('bcrypt'),
    async       = require('async'),
    request     = require('request'),
    redis       = require("redis"),
    redisClient = redis.createClient(),
    log         = require('log4node');

var io_redis    = require('socket.io-redis');

io.adapter(io_redis({host: 'localhost', port: 6379}));

require('sticky-socket-cluster/replace-console')();

require('sticky-socket-cluster')(options, start);

function start(port) {
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('login', function (data) {
            console.log(data.username);
            login(data.username, data.password, function (success, value) {
                if (success) {
                    redisClient.exists(data.username, function (err, doesExist) {
                        if (err) return;
                        if (!doesExist) {
                            log.info("saved to redis");

                            redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id, function (err, res) {
                                redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id);
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            log.info("deleted and saved to redis");

                            redisClient.del(data.username);
                            redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id, function (err, res) {
                                redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    socket.emit('login', {result: true, id: value});
                } else {
                    log.info("FAIL login");
                    socket.emit('login', {result: false});
                }
            });
        });

        socket.on('requestMoney', function (data) {
            redisClient.get('mahdi', function (err, socketId) {
                if (io.sockets.connected[socketId]) {
                    log.info('mahdi' + ' sent');
                    io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit('message', {username: 'Hey to :), inja ro bebin ;)'});
                } else {
                    log.info('mahdi' + ' NOT LOGin');
                }
            });
        });

    });

    server.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Express and socket.io listening on port ' + port);
    });
}

...
```

## Android Socket settings and options, i use namespace of this library:

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {
    ...
    public static Socket    CHAT_SOCKET;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ...
        IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
        opts.forceNew = true;
        opts.reconnection = true;

        try {
            CHAT_SOCKET = IO.socket(ClientSettings.getChatAddress(), opts);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("SOCKET.IO ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
    public Socket getSocket() {
        return CHAT_SOCKET;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know this library. Maybe, it's a template way but it happens very frequently. Are u set permissions to Internet in the manifest?

Comment: @Шах yes, all of other featur work fine when i use socket

Comment: Or it's just web-app that the user launches from browser?

Comment: @ no i dont have website for this application

Comment: You need to sure that your app sends packages. See its traffic and check packages' headers and contents to check that it's correct.

Comment: Just maybe, problem that the app doesn't try to set connection with another device. Or app doesn't run the listening server and cannot recieve a message

Comment: @Шах i checked all of that. i dont have any problem, and i can set socket id's connected users inside android, i think problem is `transport` option

Comment: Then, sorry, I will not help you. I don't know this library, I thought that problem in the protocol or server running